# How to access a list of youtube videos from android using googleapiclient?

Tags: android, youtube, google-api

I have an android app where I'm logging into g+ and retrieving some info, for which I use a GoogleApiClient object. This is supposed to be able to access all google apis depending on how you set it up. I do this for g+:

```
 mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addConnectionCallbacks(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API, Plus.PlusOptions.builder().build()).addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();
```

I'm trying to give it permision to access youtube too, but I've been unable to find what apis are available in the addApi method and how to use them. The youtube api docs use a very different method that isn't compatible with what I already have. How can I access youtube with my current code?

Answer (score 0):

add youtube permission then you can use data api. 
I'm search for use youtube api with auth.

```
GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            // scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube&
            .requestScopes(new Scope(YouTubeScopes.YOUTUBE_READONLY))
            .requestId()
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
```